# getDrawable() in Adapter Android Studio

Tags: android, interface, android-adapter

I am trying to add "Add to favourite button" in my application, so in my RecipeAdapter I created an interface. I am trying to compare two drawable images however there have different codes (I don't know how to name this?).

```
public class RecipeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    OnFavouriteButtonClickListener onFavouriteButtonClickListener;
    public TextView recipeName, description, link, ingredients;
    public ImageView imageView, addToFavouriteImageView;
    OnItemClickedListener onItemClickedListener;

    public RecipeViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemClickedListener onItemClickedListener,
                            final OnFavouriteButtonClickListener onFavouriteButtonClickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        recipeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecipeNameBreakfast);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewRecipeImageBreakfast);
        addToFavouriteImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewAddToFavourite);
        this.onItemClickedListener = onItemClickedListener;
        this.onFavouriteButtonClickListener = onFavouriteButtonClickListener;

        addToFavouriteImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (onFavouriteButtonClickListener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        Drawable d = addToFavouriteImageView.getDrawable();
                        Drawable b = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_add);
                        if (addToFavouriteImageView.getDrawable() == context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_add)) {
                            addToFavouriteImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favorite));
                            Toast.makeText(context, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            addToFavouriteImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favorite_add));
                        }
                        onFavouriteButtonClickListener.addToFavourite(position);

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onItemClickedListener.itemClicked(getAdapterPosition());
    }


    // public void OnClick()
}
```

When I try to compare Drawable d (current drawable) with drawable b they are not the same. Can somebody have any idea why they are different?

Comment: Do not compare the `Drawable`. Just have a boolean in your dataset Object `isFavorite` and use it to set favorite status inside `onBindViewHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening.

But my suggestion is instead of comparing the drawables, create another variable of boolean type which tracks the state of favourites....

if the boolean is true it is added to favourites, else not added...